# Android, дополнительное меню редактирования

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Хочу сделать меню для списков подобное этому:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сам список понимаю что, скорее всего реализован с помощью RecycleView. Вызов меню происходит по OnLongItemClick. Как сделать остальное ? Буду очень благодарен примеру.

Comment: http://www.androhub.com/android-contextual-action-mode-over-toolbar/